# Refresh dynamic layer in Google Map

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, angular-google-maps

I have created data layer object and add point data using loadGeoJson. Then attach this layer to map object using setMap().

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 6,
          center: {lat: -33.872, lng: 151.252},
        });


var layer = new google.maps.Data();

layer.loadGeoJson('https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/google.json');

layer.setMap(map);
```

I have append more points in this layer using add() function. But these new added points are not reflecting on map.

```
layer.add({geometry: new google.maps.Data.Polygon([outerCoords,innerCoords1,innerCoords2])});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you add more points, you have to refresh the layer, easy solution would be -> remember old points of layer, add new points, delete old layer, create new one with appended points.